# MySQL RegEx Huge Search

Tags: mysql, regex, concatenation

I have a database with products that gets updated weekly with now products. Each product has a column for UniqueID, Supplier, Date Added, Product Number and ReplacementID. When a product is updated it comes in with a new UniqueID but same supplierID and Product Number, so I then update old products to point to the new product (same product number, new UniqueID) with the ReplacementID. I am not find that some suppliers are simplifing their product numbers and I need to match the old with the new. 
Examples:

Old: BRB-410-12
New: BRB-410

Old: SM999 BL
New: SM999

Old: 5555i
New: 5555

Old: 346blk
New: 346

Basically I need to match up where the old product number is 1-4 "items" (space, dash, numbers or letters) longer than the new. Here is what I am trying:

```
select a.UniqueId as OLDID, b.UniqueId as NEWID
from productdata a, productdata b
where a.ProdNum REGEXP CONCAT('^', b.ProdNum, '.?.?.?.?')
and b.UniqueId > a.UniqueId
and b.DateAdded != a.DateAdded
and a.DateAdded != '2013-03-11'
and a.ProdNum !=''
and a.ReplacementId IS NULL
and b.ReplacementId IS NULL
and b.ProdNum !=''
and a.Supplier = b.Supplier);
```

Right now my database is about 800,000 products with 400,000 products already have ReplacementID. I am running this on my local machine staging database so this is the only query running, but after 20 hours it is still not working. Can you think of a better query to catch these?

I do have indexes on all used columns.

Comment: Are you using UniqueID as the primary key in your product table?  I don't quite understand why you are not just updating the existing product records.

Comment: UniqueID is the primary key, and I need to keep the old records separate for reference.